OpenCvSharp VideoCapture super slow upon Initialization
I am using OpenCvSharp's VideoCapture class to capture images from a camera, from which I use to display as a video stream. I am using this camera that is attached via USB.
The problem that I have is that when I create a new VideoCapture instance it takes around 4 to 5 seconds to complete. After the instance is created, I am setting the resolution. This takes another 4 to 5 seconds for each setting (width and height). I have played around with many different examples on how to start a new video stream from the camera, but I have had no luck in getting the library to run faster. Is there anyone that can shed some light on how to properly set up a camera stream?
Here is an example of my code that I am trying to optimize.
using OpenCvSharp;

using (var vid = new VideoCapture(0))
{
     vid.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameWidth, 640);
     vid.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameHeight, 480);

if (!vid.IsOpened())
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to open camera!");
    return;
}

while (true)
{
    // Capture the video frame
    using (var frame = new Mat())
    {
        if (!vid.Read(frame))
            break;

        // Display the frame
        Cv2.ImShow("frame", frame);

        if (Cv2.WaitKey(1) == 'q')
            break;
    }
}


Cv2.DestroyAllWindows();


I'd recommend that you use Windows-native APIs directly.

@ChristophRackwitz, I just got back on this project. Still looking for a solution. For your suggestion, do you have experience working with the native dlls? And is there an example you can point me to?

I cannot really tell you where the delays are coming from, but what can help is to select a video capture API. I tried your code with my webcam and selected VideoCaptureAPIs.DSHOW and that was much faster than the default flag.
using var vid = new VideoCapture(0, VideoCaptureAPIs.DSHOW);

From the specs of the camera you attached I see that your camera supports USB2.0 UVC Compliant MJPG/YUY2 Output, so may be it is worth a try to select VideoCaptureAPIs.OPENCV_MJPEG?
I could imagine that the VideoCaptureAPIs are optimized to certain camera hardware and therefore faster than the default option.
Mini addition - check out this simplification on"using". No curly braces needed anymore from C#8: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/using

I have tried using OPENCV_MJPEG, but it fails to open the camera. Also, prior to this new camera that I am currently using, I have used DSHOW, which worked really fast. But since switching to this new camera, the images that I am getting are all black with some static rectangles. It looks weird in other words. Any Other Suggestions?
